# Xcode 5.1.1 does not show iOS 6/7 deltas option

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios6, xcode5

I've notice that in Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008) the option foriOS 6/7 deltas is missing.
I'm using Autolayout.

Is there an equivalent menu? Has it been moved to another menu or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still exist in Xcode 5.1.1, but if you are using `AutoLayout` you won't see it.

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need Autolayout to manage different screen size (3.5-inch and 4.0-inch) but even iOS 6 and iOS 7: and I need Deltas for this !

Comment: @Fry you can not mix deltas and autolayout nor should you need it. If you need to detect the offset for the statusbar/navigationbar use the `topLayoutGuide`/`bottomLayoutGuide` on the viewcontroller

Comment: `topLayoutGuide/bottomLayoutGuide` are only available on iOS 7